# Java Concurrency in Practice “Listing 7.15". Why isShutdown and reservations are not volatile?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am reading Java Concurrency in Practice and encounter the following code snippet (Listing 7.15. Adding reliable cancellation to LogWriter.).

```
public class LogService {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private final LoggerThread loggerThread;
    private final PrintWriter writer;
    @GuardedBy("this") private boolean isShutdown;
    @GuardedBy("this") private int reservations;
    public void start() { loggerThread.start(); }
    public void stop() {
        synchronized (this) { isShutdown = true; }
        loggerThread.interrupt();
    }
    public void log(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isShutdown)
                throw new IllegalStateException(...);
            ++reservations;
        }
        queue.put(msg);
    }
    private class LoggerThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (LogService.this) {
                            if (isShutdown && reservations == 0)
                                break;
                        }
                        String msg = queue.take();
                        synchronized (LogService.this) {
                            --reservations;
                        }
                        writer.println(msg);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* retry */ } // interruption policy
                }
            } finally {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why the author didn't use volatile on `isShutdown` and `reservations`? LoggerThread can possibly cache them and work with his own copies of them
Where does i have a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both variables are exclusively accessed in `synchronized` blocks. That prevents multiple threads from accessing the variables concurrently, and enforces a happens-before relationship that ensures visibility of changes across threads.

When a critical section includes multiple operations, declaring variables involved in that critical section as volatile is not enough, because other threads can still preempt between operations with volatile variables.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about happens-before for `synchronized`

Comment: @endede, Re, "...forgot about happens-before..." But that "happens-before" is almost the entire point of `synchronized`. The point is _not_ to keep two or more different threads from executing certain code blocks at the same time. Code doesn't need synchronization. _Data_ needs synchronization. The real point of `synchronized` blocks is to ensure that the threads see a consistent and predictable view of the data that they share.